# How do I know if an application is compatible with the OS?

Tags: linux, centos, php, compatibility

---

I am on Centos 7.8

---

I wanted to know where I can find information (website or others) that will tell me if PHP 7.3 or 7.4 is compatible with my OS?

---

Answer (score 1):

You can say that a software is compatible to a given OS, as long as there are packages for that software built targeting that OS.

PHP 7.3 and 7.4 for CentOS 7 are available through [the Remi repository](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).